# kubernetes node shows limit, but no limit set

Tags: kubernetes

i have not configured any rangelimit or pod limit
but my nodes show requests and limits, is that a limit? or the max-seen value?

having around 20 active nodes all of them are the same hardware size - but each node shows diffrent limit with `kubctl describe node nodeXX`

does that mean i cannot use more than the limit?

[image: usage]

[image: cli]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the result of `kubectl describe node nodeXX` again more carefully you can see that each pod has the columns: *CPU Requests*, *CPU Limits*, *Memory Requests* and *Memory Limits*.  The total *Requests* and *Limits* as shown in your screenshot should be the sum of your pods requests and limits.
If you haven't configured limits for your pods then they will have 0%. However I can see in your screenshot that you have a node-exporter pod on your node. You probably also have pods in the kube-system namespace that you haven't scheduled yourself but are essential for kubernetes to work.

About your question:

> does that mean i cannot use more than the limit

This [article](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-resource-requests-and-limits) is great at explaining about requests and limits:

> Requests are what the container is guaranteed to get. If a container
> requests a resource, Kubernetes will only schedule it on a node that
> can give it that resource.
>
> Limits, on the other hand, make sure a container never goes above a
> certain value. The container is only allowed to go up to the limit,
> and then it is restricted.

For example: if your pod requests 1000Mi of memory and your node only has 500Mi of requested memory left, the pod will never be scheduled. If your pod requests 300Mi and has a limit of 1000Mi it will be scheduled, and kubernetes will try to not allocate more than 1000Mi of memory to it.

It may be OK to surpass 100% limit, specially in development environments, where we trade performance for capacity. Example:

[image]

Comment: thx for your great answer! infact there are pods with limits set :/